# Parametrization of rational points on the hyperboloid $z^2=-5x^2+4y^2+9$

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to find rational parametrization of the rational points on the hyperboloid $z^2=-5x^2+4y^2+9$. I found many answers about parametrization of simple hyperbolic curves, but I cannot find the case of hyperboloids. I've tried some substitutions like $\sqrt{5}x=\sqrt{4y^2+9}sin\theta,\ z=\sqrt{4y^2+9}cos\theta$ but failed. Can anyone help or recommend related materials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x={3\cos\theta\sec\alpha\over\sqrt{5}}\\y={3\cos\theta\tan\alpha\over2}\\z=3\sin\theta$$

This is the curve's parametrisation for rational points unfortunately you cant use the parametrised Pythagorean triplets $(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$ for finding the ratios because of that $\sqrt{5}$ in x you'll need to just hand pick ratios to make them rational

If say that was not an irrational number you can take 4 rational numbers and use the above parametrisation for Pythagorean triplets to make two right angled triangles  with rational sides which will have rational trig ratios for $\theta,\alpha$